# How to prevent block device like hdisk to mount, using ibudev

Tags: udev, block-device, usb-device, bind-mount

It is possible to prevent USB device to be bound using libudev (udev interface in c).

Now I want to prevent other devices like block devices to mount using it. Is it possible??
and how to do it??

Thanks!

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1667012/112466

Comment: this is udev Martin. I'm looking for it in libudev and in c program

Comment: There is no difference, because it's `udisks`. In C, you could simply generate the according rule file and reload ...trying to do this with `libudev` might only add unnecessary drama. And even if, this would be a question for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: ok i will try it. tnx alot!